# Command with localleader in gVim

Tags: vim, gvim

I'm giving gVim a try, among others because it has a [neat plugin](https://github.com/freitass/todo.txt-vim) for todo.txt.

That nice plugin in it's readme description demonstrates its usage by saying to do x you should `<localleader>x`. Looking up the help file for `<Localleader>` made me lost. I started thinking that I should map the localleader to \ by `:let maplocalleader = "\\"` but obviously I just don't get it, didn't succeeded yet.

Please elaborate on how can I use a plugin's feature by its `<localleader>x`. What should I write after `:`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just figured it out with the help of [usevim.com](http://usevim.com/2012/07/20/vim101-leader/).

There is no need to enter in the command mode by <kbd>:</kbd>, just press the local leader that by default is <kbd>\</kbd> and in 1000ms press <kbd>x</kbd>. Can be that your local leader has been set to <kbd>,</kbd> instead of <kbd>\</kbd>.